# Xcode 9.0 jammed when change tableView style in XIB,why?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode9

I updated my Xcode to 9.0,however It jammed when I changed the tableView style **Plain** into **Grouped**in XIB today,and then,I tried many times,the results are all the same,damn jam!Can anyone tell me why?An Xcode 9.0 bug?    [image]

Comment: There are lot annoying bugs in Xcode 9. Best you can do is report to Apple.

Comment: Please file in a bug report via the [Apple Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: @BadhanGanesh Yeah，I have reported to Apple.

Comment: Thanks,I have reported,bugs fly in the sky.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest Xcode 9.1 beta. Check [release notes](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.1_beta/Xcode_9.1_beta_Release_Notes.pdf).

> Fixed a hang when a UITableView was set to “grouped” style. (33483932)